# Build Table with Linq object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a column in a database that I would like to put into a table when the user searches for the ID. My thoughts are to build a table from the results of the query. The row in the DB can have a lot of `null`, empty fields and true/false.

I have the query as follows:

```
var searchQuery = Convert.ToInt32(txt_SearchId.Text);

var query = (from q in db.tblIncidents
                where q.Id == searchQuery
                select q).ToList();
```

My first Idea was to check each item in the query to see if it matched its type and if the condition was true or false(which ever it needed) to then add it to the table. I feel as if this is the wrong approach and the table row has a lot of columns.

```
foreach (var colitem in query)
      {
         if (colitem.victim != false)
            {
             headerRow.Cells.Add(thVictim);
             TableCell tcVictim = new TableCell {Text = colitem.victim.ToString()};
             row.Cells.Add(tcVictim);
             }
        *** and do the same for each column ***
       }
```

What I want to do is see if the column `is null` and if not add it to the table.
so I am after doing something like..

```
if(colitem.*property* != nulll)
  {
    row = new TableRow();
    TableCell c_Text = new TableCell();
    TableCell c_Value = new TableCell();
    tbl_Results.Rows.Add(row);
   }
```

Is there a way to check each `colitem` without explicitly adding each one?
All the fields in the DB are nullable that I want to show.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: why not use databinding?is must fast to generate table related to our DB, and filter result like you want.

Comment: You want to check all the columns or a specific one?

Comment: check all the columns

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove from the queryResult all the data you don't want before filling the table:

```
queryResult.RemoveAll(p=> p.Property == null);
```

Comment: Would I put this after i have ran the query?

Comment: @StudentRik Yes, but before filling your table.  
The Properties are those you want to check